# Angular 10: Unit Test of service "spec has no expectations"

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a very simple service that I'd like to unit test.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Step } from './step';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StepService {

  constructor() { }

  setStepDone(setDoneStep: Step) {
    setDoneStep.done = !setDoneStep.done;
  }
}
```

My tests look like this:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { StepService } from './step.service';
import { Step } from './step';

describe('StepService', () => {
  let service: StepService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(StepService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should set the done property of a step to true when done was false and setStepDone was called once', () => {
    let step: Step = { description: "test", done: false };
    service.setStepDone(step);
    expect(step.done).toBeTrue;
  });

  it('should set the done property of a step to false when done was false and setStepDone was called twice', (done) => {
    let step: Step = { description: "test", done: false };
    service.setStepDone(step);
    service.setStepDone(step);
    expect(step.done).toBeFalse;
    done();
  });
});
```

Unfortunately, when executing the tests it says:

> StepService
> should be created
> SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should set the done property of a step to true when done was false and setStepDone was called once
> SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS should set the done property of a step to false when done was false and setStepDone was called twice

So the "should be created" seems to work, but the other two have no expectations although I expect `step.done` to be true or false.

Why doesn't it recognize the `expect(...)` statements?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*tobeTrue* is a function, so you need to add parentheses to call it properly (same with *toBeFalse*)

```
expect(step.done).toBeTrue();
```

The test will now find a testable expectation.